# Fill up 1 form data using data attribute in another form with jquery

Tags: php, jquery, forms, laravel-5

In my laravel 5 ecommerce web application, I am trying to fill up `shipping_address` form values same as `billing_address` form values if the `checkbox` of `name = same_as_billing` is checked.

I am trying to do this using `data-*` attribute, but I am failing to achieve my goal.

What I want is: `billing_address` form values should fill up `shipping_address` form values automatically using `data-values` attribute.

Here's the form `billing_address`:

```
<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('address_1', 'Address 1:') !!}
    {!! Form::text('address_1', $billing->address_1, ['class' => 'form-control input-sm', 'data-values' => $billing->address_1]) !!}
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('address_2', 'Address 2:') !!}
    {!! Form::text('address_2', $billing->address_2, ['class' => 'form-control input-sm', 'data-values' => $billing->address_2]) !!}
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('area', 'Area:') !!}
    {!! Form::text('area', $billing->area, ['class' => 'form-control input-sm', 'data-values' => $billing->area]) !!}
</div>

<!-- Rest of the form values -->
```

Here's the form `shipping_address`:

```
<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::checkbox('same_as_billing', 'same_as_billing', false, ['id' => 'same_as_billing']) !!}
    <label for="same_as_billing">Shipping Address Same As Billing Address</label>
</div>

<div class='shippingAddressFormFields'>
    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('address_1', 'Address 1:') !!}
        {!! Form::text('address_1', $billing->address_1, ['class' => 'form-control input-sm']) !!}
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('address_2', 'Address 2:') !!}
        {!! Form::text('address_2', $billing->address_2, ['class' => 'form-control input-sm']) !!}
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('area', 'Area:') !!}
        {!! Form::text('area', $billing->area, ['class' => 'form-control input-sm']) !!}
    </div>
</div>

    <!-- Rest of the form values -->
```

The jquery code that I have tried:

```
var inputField = $('.shippingAddressFormFields').find('input');
inputField.val('');
var selectField = $('.shippingAddressFormFields').find('select');
selectField.val('');

$('#same_as_billing').on('click', function() {
    if( $(this).is(':checked') ) {
        inputField.prop('readonly', true);
        selectField.prop('disabled', true);

        $("[data-values]").filter(function() {
            return $(this).data('values');
        }).each(function(e, v) {
            v.value = $("[data-values]").data('values');

            console.log(e + ": " + v.value);
        });

    } else {
        inputField.prop('readonly', false);
        selectField.prop('disabled', false);

        inputField.val('');
        selectField.val('');
    }
});
```

The output of `console.log(e + ": " + v.value);` which is wrong:

```
0: BAK Building, This Colony // <-- address_1 - correct
1: BAK Building, This Colony // <-- address_2 - incorrect
```

The **desired output** of `console.log(e + ": " + v.value);` should be :

```
0: BAK Building, This Colony // <-- address_1 - correct
1: That Road, Some Landmark // <-- address_2 - correct
```

The desired output should fill up the `shipping_address` form values.

How can I achieve that ?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're accessing the value incorrectly from `$.each`, your current code will only return the first `data-values` I think, which is why it's not working.

Try `console.log(v.dataset.values);` instead.

You can then bind the values as so:

```
$('.shippingAddressFormFields [name="' +  v.getAttribute("name") + '"]')
    .val(v.dataset.values);
```

See working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ntp3Lqpj/2/